# Regex group words seperated by whitespace

Tags: php, regex

I have a question concerning Regex and I hope to get some help. I have a bootstrap code containing several expressions like [col md-6 lg-2] or just [col md-6]. However the amount of columns is not fixed and I can have like [col x y z] or even more.

I'd like to achieve a match with groups like: 
Group 1: x 
Group 2: y
Group 3: z
... and so on.

Some help would be much appreciated

best regards

Comment: @user3783243 I think those `[col md-6 lg-2]` etc. are strings in the Bootstrap code and the question is how to match them with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to separate your group with `preg_replace_callback` then split the found string on spaces. Something like this should do it

```
$return = '';
preg_replace_callback('/\[col \K[^\]]+/', function($match){
    $GLOBALS['return'] = preg_split('/\s+/', $match[0], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}, '[col md-6 lg-2]');
print_r($return);
```

https://3v4l.org/koKFH

This `\[col \K` is looking for the literal string `[col` then the `\K` tells the regex to forget it matched that for the capturing. The `[^\]]+` then captures everything until the next `]`. We then use that found group in the callback to separate on whitespaces (`\s`).

Comment: This actually makes sense, never thought about splitting it up. I am still not that good with regex. Thanks a lot for your quick answer. I will try to implement that in my code to replace all those strings.